# Override Authorizer for only one lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I'm taking over a SAM template where the previous dev has an authorizer on API Gateway which forces every lambda function to pass along a Cognito token in order to secure the API.

```
Auth:
  DefaultAuthorizer: AuthStackCognitoAuthorizer
  AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: False
  Authorizers:
    AuthStackCognitoAuthorizer:
      UserPoolArn:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${AuthStack}-UserPoolArn"
```

The problem comes in when I want one specific lambda function attached to API Gateway to NOT have an authorizer. Is there a way I can modify my lambda so that it's not requiring the overarching APIGateway Authorizer?

```
  PostFeedbackLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/endpoints/feedback/post
      Handler: index.handler
      Description: Returns feedback.
      Layers:
        - !Ref CommonUtilsLayer
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: POST
            Path: /feedback
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayApi
```